# Ввод и вывод строковых данных на консоль

Tags: java

Здравствуйте! Подскажите по коду, что можно переделать или добавить?

Задание:

> Создать программу, которая будет проверять, является ли слово из пяти букв, введённое пользователем, палиндромом (примеры: «комок», «ротор»). Если введено слово не из 5 букв, то сообщать об ошибке. Программа должна нормально обрабатывать слово, даже если в нём использованы символы разного регистра. Например, слова «Комок» или «РОТОР» следует также считать палиндромами.

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String args []){
        Scanner sr = new Scanner(System.in);
         String s;
        System.out.print("Введите слово из 5 букв -> ");
        if(sr.hasNext()){
          s = sr.next();
           if(s.length()==5){
               s.toLowerCase();
               s.toUpperCase();
          System.out.print(s);
        }else{System.out.println("!!!Ошибка_Ввода!!!");}}
    }
}
```

Еще такой вопрос: как написать код, чтоб допустим при вводе целого или вещественного числа выдавал ошибку, так как должен использоваться только строковый ввод?

Comment: А где у вас, собственно, проверка на палиндром?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Думаю, такое решение сойдёт:

```
public static boolean isPolindrom(String s) {
    if (s.charAt(0) == s.charAt(4) &&
            s.charAt(1) == s.charAt(3))
        return true;
    return false;
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    Scanner sr = new Scanner(System.in);
    String s;
    boolean isString = true;
    System.out.print("Введите слово из 5 букв -> ");
    if (sr.hasNext()) {
        // Для Windows кодировка введёных данных cp1251
        // Если Unix, то скорее всего будет koi8-r
        s = new String(sr.next().getBytes("cp1251"));
        try {
            // Проверяем введено ли число
            Double.parseDouble(s);
            isString = false;
        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {}
        if (s.length() != 5) {
            System.out.println("!!!Ошибка_Ввода!!! Не 5 букв");
        } else if(!isString) {
            System.out.println("!!!Ошибка_Ввода!!! Введено число");
        } else {
            if (isPolindrom(s))
                System.out.println(s + " - палиндром");
            else
                System.out.println(s + " - не палиндром");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Спасибо, @dude, так пойдет.